# Calculate angle (degree) of a straight line

Tags: python, matplotlib, trigonometry, angle, degrees

I'm trying to determine angle in degrees of a straight line of two points, I came across many solutions online but none of them worked for me, consider this piece of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.array([7405.,7447.4,7433.99,7410.,7443.15,7429.4,7590.03,7550.,7566.32,7619.62,7549.71,7551.8,7530,7522.99,7499.75,7453.99,7542.16,7564.,7552.77,7552])
y = [7606.672474,7570.240928]
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot([6,17], y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The target line is `y` it should be around -5 degrees just by looking at it.
It seems like most online solutions suggest that we can find the angle by doing

```
degree = np.math.atan2(y[-1] - y[0], x[-1] - x[0])
degree = np.degrees(degree)
```

I omitted the other values of y to just the first and last point for simplicity so the `x[-1] - x[0]` part here would be 11=17-6 which is the length of y line across the x-axis, this is what most online solutions suggest, however all the approaches failed to get the right angle for this, I should note that during my tests some approaches *seemed* to give the right angle for a given data unit for example while totally failing on a different data unit like

```
data = [52.3384984,53.04757978,52.04276249,51.77348257,49.93056673,52.24062341,55.74022485,60.77761392,60.89290148,60.1995072,60.40524964,59.00590344,59.67589831,56.49266698,49.02464746,51.53876823,57.77368203,59.48092106,56.63155446,56.0648491 ]
y = [51.337288,50.331895]
plt.plot(data)
plt.plot([3,15], y)
plt.show()
```

I also tried to min-max normalize the data but no success, so considering we have the first and last point of a line and its length how can we or is it possible to determine its angle in degrees?

Comment: soh-cah-toa... sin = opposite/hypotenuse, cos = adjacent/hypotenuse, tan = opposite/adjacent. . . and since the length is the hypotenuse, and you have the opposite and adjacent as well. . . any method will work, I think?  See: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ttrig.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two angles you need to understand. The first one is calculated based data, the second one is calculated based on figure.

### First one

The code you wrote is calculating first one:

```
degree = np.math.atan2(y[-1] - y[0], x[-1] - x[0])
degree = np.degrees(degree)
```

It's `delta_y = y[-1] - y[0] = -36.43`, `delta_x = x[-1] - x[0] = 11`

`degree = -73.20` which totally make sense if you draw a triangle in your mind.

### Second one

However, you may question me that you are watching a line around -5 degree. That's second one which involve calculating display ratio, (notice y axis and x axis has different unit length in inches). Here I found a separated question to help you calculate that.

```
from operator import sub
def get_aspect(ax):
    # Total figure size
    figW, figH = ax.get_figure().get_size_inches()
    # Axis size on figure
    _, _, w, h = ax.get_position().bounds
    # Ratio of display units
    disp_ratio = (figH * h) / (figW * w)
    # Ratio of data units
    # Negative over negative because of the order of subtraction
    data_ratio = sub(*ax.get_ylim()) / sub(*ax.get_xlim())

    return disp_ratio / data_ratio
```

So you need multiple that ratio to get manhattan distance of line end points.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ratio = get_aspect(ax)
degree = np.math.atan2((y[-1] - y[0])*ratio, x[-1] - x[0])
degree = np.degrees(degree)
```

The result is -4.760350735146195 which is around -5.

Comment: Interesting, I've tried with different data but it seems to fail eg: `y = [7533, 7638]` with length 7=[5,12] [image](https://i.imgur.com/DnwPRzC.png) it gives 5.3° while it looks almost 45°

Comment: Normalizing `y` to the range of `x` (0-19) making them of the same unit/length seem to give the right angle using just the _standard_ equation `degrees(atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1))`

Comment: @0x3h I'm not totally agree that your ratio is as sample as unit/length. But I think you are right. Something I mentioned is wrong. `atan2` isn't linear, so ratio has to be used before calculating `atan2`. I updated code. Now it should make sense in both cases.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks, now it gives 11.23 which is real angle _as we see it_ [link](https://i.imgur.com/OjYLY2M.png)